# Send get request to api endpoint using useEffect did not fetch data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, request, axios, use-effect

I have an api endpoint that returns an array of data. 
I want to make a get request to this endpoint when the react-native component first mount.
I tried to do it in `useEffect`, making an HTTP request with `axios` executing asynchronously.
The `useEffect` did get executed, but I am not sure if the request was ever made (it doesn't seem like so because the `console.log` inside never executed).

The request never reached the endpoint that's for sure.

Here is the code:

```
export default function App() {
  let [items, setItems] = useState({});
  // fetch data on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect ran"); // ---------- this was logged
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "x-auth-token":
          "some-token",
      },
    };
    async () => {
      console.log("here") // ---------- NEVER RAN!! WHY??
      try {
        const res = await axios.get("/api/consultations", config);
        
        (some data processing code...)

        console.log(items);

        // update items in state
        setItems(items);
      } catch (err) {
        // Server error
        console.error(err);
      }
    };
  }, [items]);

  return (
    <Agenda
      style={styles.calendarList}
      items={items}
      renderItem={(item) => {
        return <ConsultationMeeting meeting={item} />;
      }}
      renderEmptyData={() => {
        return (
          <View style={styles.message}>
            <Text style={{ ...styles.mediumFont, color: "gray" }}>
              No Scheduled Appointment
            </Text>
          </View>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: give your async function a name ( inside or outside useEffect) and call it inside useEffect

Comment: @Aymen Worked! Now it comes back with a `Network Error` haha but the logs are not really helpful. How should I go about debugging when there's a network error in react-native?

Comment: you can use Flipper
https://fbflipper.com/docs/features/react-native/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the api call but never called it

```
export default function App() {
  let [items, setItems] = useState({});
  // fetch data on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect ran"); // ---------- this was logged
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "x-auth-token":
          "some-token",
      },
    };
    (async () => {
      console.log("here") // ---------- NEVER RAN!! WHY??
      try {
        const res = await axios.get("/api/consultations", config);
        
        (some data processing code...)

        console.log(items);

        // update items in state
        setItems(items);
      } catch (err) {
        // Server error
        console.error(err);
      }
    })()
  }, [items]);

  return (
    <Agenda
      style={styles.calendarList}
      items={items}
      renderItem={(item) => {
        return <ConsultationMeeting meeting={item} />;
      }}
      renderEmptyData={() => {
        return (
          <View style={styles.message}>
            <Text style={{ ...styles.mediumFont, color: "gray" }}>
              No Scheduled Appointment
            </Text>
          </View>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Try this, Wraping async function in auto function call.

Answer (score 0):

Try using async in use effect instead of the middle.

`

```
export default function App() {
  let [items, setItems] = useState({});
  // fetch data on mount`enter code here`
  useEffect(async () => {`enter code here`
    console.log("useEffect ran"); // ---------- this was logged
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "x-auth-token":
          "some-token",
      },
    };

      console.log("here") // ---------- NEVER RAN!! WHY??
      try {
        const res = await axios.get("/api/consultations", config);
        
        (some data processing code...)

        console.log(items);

        // update items in state
        setItems(items);
      } catch (err) {
        // Server error
        console.error(err);
      }
   
  }, [items]);`
```

Comment: I did this the first time. React-native said I can't put the async there, and that i should define an async function inside and call it instead. The reason for my problem is that the annonymous async function never get called. @Ayman 's comment worked. Appreciate the help tho!